# MYSQL select max date from joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, max

I have 2 tables which I want to join and retrieve some specific data. These are my tables.

```
tbl_user (reg_id, l_name, f_name, status)

tbl_payments (pay_id, reg_id, mem_plan, from_date, to_date, bill_no, payed_date)
```

What I need to do is select and view the users who have due payments. To do that I want to get the user details where `"status=0"` from `tbl_user` and join the 2 tables together and the conditions are `to_date< current date`, difference between `[current date and the to_date] < 31` and filter by the Max value of `to_date`.

What I did so far gives me a result according to above mentioned conditions except it dosen't filter by the `MAX(to_date)`. This is my query.

```
SELECT
       A.reg_id, 
       A.f_name, 
       A.l_name, 
       B.mem_plan, 
       B.from_date, 
       Max(B.to_date) AS to_date, 
       B.bill_no, 
       B.payed_date 
FROM
       tbl_user A, 
       tbl_payments B 
WHERE
       A.status = 0 
       AND A.reg_id = B.reg_id 
       AND Date(Now()) >= Date(B.to_date) 
       AND Datediff(Date(Now()), Date(b.to_date)) < 31
GROUP BY
       a.reg_id, b.mem_plan, b.from_date, b.bill_no, b.payed_date;
```

I'm not very familiar with MYSQL, So please someone tell me what I did wrong or if this query is not up to the standard.

---

Here are some sample data to work on.

tbl_user ( [M1111,Jon, Doe,0], [M1112,Jane,Doe,1],[M1113,Jony,Doe,0] )

tbl_payment ( [1,M1111,Monthly,2018-05-14,2018-06-14,b123,2018-05-14],[2,M1112,3Months,2018-02-03,2018-05-03,b112,2018-02-03],[3,M1113,Monthly,2018-06-14,2018-07-14,b158,2018-06-14],[4,M1111,Monthly,2018-06-15,2018-07-15,b345,2018-06-15],[5,M1113,Monthly,2018-06-06,2018-07-06,b158,2018-06-06],[6,M1111,Monthly,2018-07-05,2018-08-05,b345,2018-07-05] )

Assuming current date is 2018-07-17, The expecting result should be this

[M1111,Jon,Doe,Monthly,2018-06-15,2018-07-15,b345,2018-06-15],[M1113,Jony,Doe,Monthly,2018-06-14,2018-07-14,b158,2018-06-14]

Instead of that, my query gives me this.

[M1111,Jon,Doe,Monthly,2018-06-15,2018-07-15,b345,2018-06-15],[M1113,Jony,Doe,Monthly,2018-06-06,2018-07-06,b158,2018-06-06],
[M1113,Jony,Doe,Monthly,2018-06-14,2018-07-14,b158,2018-06-14]

Comment: There is no reg_to in your tables. Is it reg_to or to_date?

Comment: Make sure you group by all non-aggregate columns, then look into the `GROUP BY ... HAVING to_date = max(to_date)`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Yes @GCadogan, reg_to supposed to be date_to. Ihave corrected my mistakes on the question. Thank you..

Comment: @D-Shih I added some sample data to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote another query which gives me the result set exactly as i want. But I'm not sure whether it's up to the standards. If someone can simplify this or make it better, appreciate very much.

```
SELECT A.reg_id,A.f_name,A.l_name,D.mem_plan,D.from_date,D.to_date,D.bill_no,D.payed_date
FROM tbl_user A
JOIN (SELECT B.reg_id,B.mem_plan,B.from_date,B.to_date,B.bill_no,B.payed_date
FROM tbl_payments B
JOIN (
SELECT reg_id, MAX(to_date) as to_date
FROM tbl_payments
WHERE DATE(NOW()) >= DATE(to_date) AND DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(to_date))<31
GROUP BY reg_id) C
ON B.reg_id = C.reg_id AND B.to_date= C.to_date) D
ON A.reg_id = D.reg_id
WHERE A.status=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `having` won't work here and that your second query is about as good as it gets. I've condensed it a little here:

```
 SELECT A.reg_id,f_name,l_name,mem_plan,from_date,to_date,bill_no,payed_date
 FROM @tbl_user A
 JOIN  @tbl_payments B ON A.reg_id = b.reg_id
 JOIN (
    SELECT reg_id, MAX(to_date) as max_to_date
    FROM @tbl_payments
    WHERE DATE(NOW()) >= DATE(to_date) AND DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(to_date))<31
    GROUP BY reg_id
 ) C ON B.reg_id = C.reg_id AND B.to_date= C.max_to_date
 WHERE A.status=0;
```